# awk sed help needed to create a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, tr

Hi I have an input file with entries. Each line starts with a hostname ( host1, host2).
I need to create a file name after the hostname that will contain list of entries on each line after the colon. Can someone assist?  Please see example below

input file

```
host1*stop*start : runit stopit gather 
host2*stop*start : unite cease cut chop eat
```

output file name host1

```
runit 
stopit 
gather
```

output file name host2

```
unite 
cease 
cut 
chop 
eat
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '{n=split($1,array,"*"); for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) {print $i >array[1]}}' input
```

The above uses whitespace as a field separator.  Consequently, for your first example line, the first field is `host1*stop*start`, the second is `:`, and the rest are: `runit`, `stopit`, `gather`.  We first need to extract the hostname from the the first field.  We do this by splitting that field on the character `*` which puts the hostname in the variable `array[1]`.  Then, we write the third field and all thereafter as separate lines to the file named by `array[1]`.

Comment: ITYM `>`, not `>>`. The awk semantics are different from shell. No need to save the split() return code and split takes an RE as an arg so unless there's some reason to use an RE contained in a string, the `//` delimiters should be used for clarity and simplicity (for more complicated REs). +1 by the way :-).

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks. Yes, the n= is optional. By the way, I checked the [GNU awk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), and it says that >> should be used for append ([See Sec. 5.6](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Redirection)) although in this case > protects the user against multiple runs of the code (change made). Also according to the manual Sec. 9.1.3, the third arg to `split` is called `fieldsep` and, in Sec 6.1.2, the manual notes that only modern versions of `awk` allow a regex constant there.

Comment: `>>` is for when you specifically NEED to append to an existing file, when you just want to create a file as the OP stated, then it's `>`. Yes, the 3rd arg is named fieldsep in the man page and it's an RE that's treated the same way as the REs in FS wrt field splitting (e.g. treats a single space char specially) and the only awk I'm aware of that might not allow a RE constant there is old, broken awk which should never be used. If you specify a string instead, then you need to worry about awk double-parsing it and so need to double quote RE metachars that you want taken as literal.

Answer (score 4):

Using just [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) builtins:

```
while IFS=: read -a ln; do
    printf "%s\n" ${ln[@]:1} > "${ln[0]%%\**}"
done < file.txt
```

- Reads and splits each line on `:` into an array
- The 0th element of the array will be e.g. "host1*stop*start".  This is turned into the required filename by using a parameter expansion to delete every `*` and all following text
- All remaining elements will be a space-separated list.  This is passed to printf, which will format each member of that list according to its format specifier
- The printf output is redirected to the filename generated above

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl`:

```
perl -lane '$,="\n";$F[0]=~/([^*]+)/;open(O,">$1");print O @F[2..$#F];close(O)' file
```

#### With comments:

```perl
perl -lane '             # Split the line on space and load them in an array
    $,="\n";             # Set the output list separator to newline
    $F[0] =~ /([^*]+)/;  # Capture the file name from first array index
    open(O,">$1");       # Open a file handle with filename using captured group
    print O @F[2..$#F];  # print everything from 3rd index to end of line in that file
    close(O)             # Close the file handle
' file
```

Comment: Thanks this works as well. not sure how .. but thank u

Comment: @theuniverseisflat You're welcome. I added some comments for you. Hope that helps.